# count between 2 inputted numbers (range) & display each

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

My attempt is below; to first start with a `while loop` to create the array, then iterate through each with a `foreach` in attempt to count each item in array.

```
$begin = $_POST['startpoint'];
$end = $_POST['endpoint'];

$current_start = $begin;

$num1 = 3;
$num2 = 355;

while ($i = $begin; $i <= $end; ++$i) {
    $array[] = $i;
  foreach ($array as &$counted) {
    echo '<span>Star SC ' + $counted + ' mag ' + $num1 + $num2;
  }    
}
```

---

the desired output would be something like this; if user inserted say `10002` and `80000`:

**Output 1.)**  Star C `69998` mag...

*and*

**Output 2.)**

```
10002
10003
10004
10005
```

(all the way to `80000`)

---

html:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">

  <input type="number" name="startpoint" min="100000" max="999998">
  <input type="number" name="endpoint" min="100001" max="999999">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />

</form>
```

---

**more details**: I would like to count, so do the math between each user inputed number (ie. `69998`); and display each numbers between, so with the above user example; it would be `10002`, `10003`, `10004` - all the way to `80000` .

Comment: You just want to do the math?

Comment: you have wrong use of while loop, you should be using `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is output each line you would do it like this:

```
$begin = 10002;
$end = 80000;

$current_start = $begin;

$num1 = 3;
$num2 = 355;

for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    echo '<span>Star SC ' . $i . ' mag ' . $num1 .', '. $num2;
}
```

`.` is concatenation in PHP, not `+` and you need a `for()` loop, not a `while()`. In addition, you do not need to utilize yet another array for your output.

Output is

```
<span>Star SC 10002 mag 3, 355
...
<span>Star SC 80000 mag 3, 355
```

Answer (score 2):

I really do not understand your intention, but for a memory friendly solution, you should use generator function.

```
function numbers_between($n1, $n2) {
  for($n1; $n1 <= $n2; $n1++) {
    yield $n1;
  } 
}
$generator = numbers_between(1,5);

foreach($generator as $genval){
  echo $genval."\n";
}
```

if you want the total number count, just do basic math, like

```
($num2 - $num1)+1
```

[link to working code snippet](https://repl.it/@marmeladze1/MiniatureGloomyFrontpage)

Comment: sorry, i was going to write intention -)) it was a typo

Comment: gotchya, how is the intention confusing? just two output objectives?

Comment: no, i mean, why on the earth would you like to output zillions of numbers line by line -)))

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is

```
foreach (range($begin, $end) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```