# validate input value of min and max

Tags: php, loops, constants

I know this can be validated with HTML now, but also need to validate on PHP side.

```
<input type="number" name="startpoint" min="100000" max="999998">
<!-- input one, but will validate 2, this is `startpoint`, other is ending or `MAX_VALUE`-->
```

i essentially need to validate the same which is being validated above in my mark-up; but within PHP side.

```
while ($_POST['startpoint'] => 100000 || =< 999998) { 

    for (){ // run for loop

    }

}
```

Comment: is this related to your previous post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49949371/

Comment: or will you not bother commenting here? You did the same thing for your other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wrong comparison operator.

```
while ($_POST['startpoint'] >= 100000 && $_POST['startpoint'] <= 999998) {
```